# "Additional cross-cloud API support" in the Delphi Roadmap

Tags: delphi, azure, amazon-ec2, cloud

In section "other features under consideration", the [RAD Studio / Delphi / C++Builder Roadmap](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39934) for Pulsar lists

> Additional cross-cloud API support

This sounds interesting - what does *cross-cloud* API mean technically?

Is this an API which integrates different cloud providers as explained in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_API#Cross-platform_cloud_APIs)?

Comment: Since Delphi XE has some Azure (Microsoft) features, and some Amazon EC2 features, my guess is that this refers to extensions or improvements to what was in XE already.  Secondly, such a question is affected by an NDA, so anybody who knows for sure all the details on unreleased products can not say. Thus this question is unanswerable in its current form, so I have voted to close.  Pulsar (Rad Studio XE2) is still under NDA, and only that which has been publicly disclosed by Embarcadero on public sources can be cited by those who in the know.

Comment: @Warren, you can glean an awful lot when there is a presentation on the topic. Furthermore, the reason Embarcadero have embarked on the World Tour is so that people like me (and others) can spill the beans and generate a buzz for the new version. You are too quick on the draw on this occasion ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just means re-factoring to make it easier to switch between the two (as demonstrated on the XE2 World Tour). There is a lot of commonality across the two services so as much as they can they have tried to make their use compatible.